# Resizing an image to fit in multiple shapes throughout Site w/ CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to resize an image using CSS so it fits in multiple shapes throughout a blog. ie. fits in the featured category 280x200, fits in the recent posts 330x110, and then full size when it's opened in full_post.php.  I don't want to crop & specify thumbnails in the CMS, would rather have the CSS just re-work the image for display.  Here is how I have it setup:

HTML:

```
<ul class="list-categories">
        <li>
            <h2><a href="#">Featured 4</a></h2>
            <a href="fullpost.php?id=<?php echo $PostId4; ?>"><img src="assets/upload/<?php echo $Image4;?>" alt=""></a>
        </li>
```

CSS:

```
.list-categories {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -13px;
  margin-right: -14px;
}
.list-categories li {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 13.5px;
  padding-right: 13.5px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .list-categories li {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
  }
}
.list-categories li img {
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

I've tried position: relative in .list categories and object-fit & object-position in li img, but no success.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, 
ep

Comment: Have you considered setting it as a background image for your divs and applying the "cover" attribute?  This will auto scale, and autocrop for you.

Comment: The images are being pulled from the dB so I can't set them in css unless I use inline.  Would rather not go that route as image names/formats could change when input in CMS.